# Where can I find the Halakhot of the Rif in French or English?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, translation, rif-rabbi-isaac-alfasi

I am looking for the halakhot of the Rif in translation, either French or English.
Where can I find these?  As a paper book or e-book, I don't really care.

Answer (score 7):

At [Alfasi.blogspot.com](http://alfasi.blogspot.com/), I have translated the Rif (into English) for the following masechtot:

- bava batra
- bava kamma
- beitza
- brachot
- chagiga
- eruvin
- gittin
- ketubot
- kiddushin
- megillah
- moed katan
- nedarim
- niddah
- pesachim
- rosh hashana
- shabbat
- succah
- taanit
- yevamot
- yoma

Comment: Thank you. Did you translate only parts or all the Rif for these masechtot?

Comment: All.  I don't recall for the very last in the sequence whether I completed it

Comment: Last would be bava  batra

Comment: Thanks. It would be awesome if you translate the other masechtot! You did an incredible job!